# How to Export and Import Views in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

we run exchange 2010 and our clients are running Outlook 2007. In the public folder, we have created a couple of shared Task folders. Logged in as the administrator, we have given the appropriate permissions, created a new list called HF and defined the views for it. I then give the permissions to the rest of the users which are Editor permission. When I log in as a test user, I can access the HF Task but I don't see the custom defined view for it. I'm not sure how to get that to show up for everyone. 
Views are not stored in the Public Folder. They are stored in Outlook or a user's Exchange mailbox. You would need to export the view and import it on the viewers' computers for them to have it. There should be a group policy option for importing views without having to do it manually, though.

Can anyone give me a step by step guide as to how to do those last 2 sentences I have searched far and wide through the internet and for the life of me cannot figure oout how to export the view or import it on others computers. I also cannot figure out this group policy option for importing views without having to do it manually either. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that GPO provide anything for customizing Outlook views. Anyway, take a look at the [Setting Outlook Group Policies](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/policies.htm) page for more information on that.

The Outlook object model provides the [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864185(v=office.15).aspx) object which represents a customizable view used to sort, group, and view data. Here is what MSDN states:

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419(v=office.15).aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

So, you can export and import the XML value of the view programmatically.